# "für die Party" or "zur Party"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Which sentence is correct?

```
Ich lade dich für die Party ein (Akkusative)
```

or

```
Ich lade dich zur Party ein (Dativ)
```

or

Both are correct based on *für* or *zu*?

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What makes you think one of them is wrong? Please clarify what you mean with the last question, I cannot interpret it.

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic phrase is

> jemand *zu etwas* einladen (Dativ)

The phrase "jemand *für etwas* einladen (Akkusativ)" would be certainly understood; but it sounds very strange if not even wrong to a native speaker's ear.